# How do I configure my SQL Server instance to use a different Edition with minimal side effects?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, mirroring, instance

I'm in the process of migrating an old server running *Windows 2008 R2* with *SQL 2012 Express* to a new server running *SQL Server 2017 Standard* and *Windows 2016*. I would like to mirror databases between them, but the Express Edition doesn't support it. I tried to upgrade it to *SQL 2012 Standard Evaluation*, but I received the following error:

> Failed The selected SQL Server instance does not
>   meet upgrade matrix requirements.

I discovered this isn't possible:
[Upgrade SQL Server 2012 Express to Evaluation Edition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37283/upgrade-sql-server-2012-express-to-evaluation-edition)

I was forced to install *SQL Server 2012 Evaluation* as a new side-by-side instance and named it **./SQLSERVER2**. In order to use this instance, however, it would require moving a ton of data files and changing the instance names in all my configuration files. This will also require server downtime as well. This will be a major PITA without the humous and I want to avoid it if at all possible.

Is there a way of reconfiguring **./SQLSERVER** to use the *Standard Evaluation Edition* with minimal downtime and side-effects?

Comment: Install them side by side, then backup the database from Express Edition and restore it to Standard Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly follow these steps to "migrate" the databases to a "new" SQL Server 20xx instance.

1. `detach` the databases in the running SQL Server Express instance and leave them where they are.
2. Script out any logins that you require.
3. Don't delete/drop any databases.
4. De-install the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.
5. Install the SQL Server 20xx Standard Edition. (you can even use the instance name SQLEXPRESS; how clever is that?)
6. Add the SQL Server Logins to your "new" SQL Server 20xx Standard Edition instance.
7. Once the "new" SQL Server 20xx Standard Edition is running `attach` the "old" databases to your new SQL Server 20xx instance.
8. Change the database compatibility level to 110 (if required).

Enjoy a "new" SQL Server 20xx Standard Edition instance hosting your "old" databases.